# why sometimes adding @ with the username doesnot works at stackoverflow

Tags: support, bug, site-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

On stackoverflow site while referring to the questionnaire i usually add `@` symbol but sometimes its works and sometimes not. Example, Let say user "XYZ" posted a question and i m adding comment with refering to the user like "@XYZ" but sometimes it works and pasted as @XYZ on submit but sometimes not. Let me know if i am missing something with the usage to refer to the questionnaire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot refer to a user in his/her own post(question/answer) (because they will be notified anyway)
2. You can refer only one user in a single post/comment

More Details:

> The owner of the post you're commenting on will always be notified of
>   your comment. If you are replying to someone else who has previously
>   commented on the same post, mention their username: @peter and
>   @PeterSmith will both notify a previous commenter named “Peter Smith”.
>
> It is generally sufficient to mention only the first name of the user
>   whose comment you are replying to, e.g. @ben or @marc. However you may
>   need to be more specific if three people named Ben replied in earlier
>   comments, by adding the first character of the last name, e.g. @benm
>   or @benc Spaces are not valid in comment reply names, so don't use
>   @peter smith, always enter it as @peters or @petersmith.
>
> If the user you're replying to has no natural first name and last
>   name, simply enter enough characters of the name to make it clear who
>   you are responding to. Three is the minimum, so if you're replying to
>   Fantastico, enter @fan, @fant, or @fantastic.
>
> You can use the same method to notify any editor of the post, or – if
>   this is the case – to the ♦ moderator who closed the question.

Source

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply
- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: this is not what im looking for :( it sometimes works so  this is not the case bro :)

Comment: @swapnesh Then check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).