# Please update/fix markdown help for comment-replies

Tags: support, status-completed, markdown, display-names, comment-replies

Please update/fix the markdown help page for the usage of comment @username

[This markdown help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply) is the one linked to when you click on "advanced help" when entering a comment/question/answer.

I noticed from the #tag (#comment-reply) in one of the links & looking at the source that it actually contains help for this... it just doesn't appear on the page.

**Additional detail** *I had already written all of the following before I looked at the source for the help page so I thought I'd just leave it in (in case it could do with updating)*:

It took me about 15 minutes to track down what it's called (it has no name) and how to use it, but I eventually came across these questions that were extremely helpful:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155/225599
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145035/225599 - this reply actually refers to the above-mentioned help page which doesn't actually contain help on it's usage
- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

What I found particularly useful were these comments (taken from those posts):

- You cannot refer to a user in his/her own post(question/answer) (because they will be notified anyway)
- You can refer only one user in a single post/comment
- If a comment thread contains a comment by a user whose name starts with a non-ASCII letter, then just typing @ will bring the tab completer up with that name